# Google Cloud Vision PDF Gibberish

Tags: pdf, ocr, text-extraction, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to extract text from PDF files using the Google Cloud Vision API. It works most of the times, but I get gibberish in a few cases. I tried both DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION, I tried forcing the language in the languageHints but it didn't help.

Then I tried with a screenshot saved as tiff and this did work, so I'm guessing that Google tries to use the text in the PDF if it's not just a picture. Indeed, when I select all "text" in the PDF, I get gibberish.

When I print the tiff back into PDF, text extraction works. So it's really something weird with the PDF. But other extraction software (such as abbyy) work well with the original PDF.

Has anyone had the same kind of issues?

One thing that could help would be an option to force treat the PDF as an "image PDF". Is there such an option?

Thanks for your help!

FYI, I am unfortunately not allowed to show the PDF, and I use the dotnet library.

Edit:
The info on the PDF is:

```
Creator: "PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2"
Producer: Acrobat Distiller 10.1.16 (Windows)
```

Comment: I understand you can't share the pdfs, but are you able to re-create the issue with your own sample pdf? What is the language? By gibberish, are you saying random letters in that language?

Comment: The issue is consistent with the same PDF. By gibberish i mean stuff like "ÿ ÿ5 and a lot of spaces. The language is english.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with a pdf file that you can share?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a PDF that I can share. The info on the PDF is: Creator: "PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2", Producer: Acrobat Distiller 10.1.16 (Windows)